# How to disable CapsLock in console?

Tags: keyboard, capslock

I can disable <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> in the GUI using following command:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
```

But how can I disable it completely in the console, on a machine without X/GUI ?

Comment: Check this out:https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dumpkeys | sed s/Caps_Lock/Control/ | loadkeys
```

On Debian and alike, just putting `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"` in `/etc/default/keyboard` works for both the console and X11 -- provided that you have the `console-setup` package installed. Use the `setupcon` command to immediately re-load that file.

Comment: adding `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"` to `/etc/default/keyboard` has no effect. And I don't have `dumpkeys` command and cannot find package to install it on Debian.

Comment: `dumpkeys` is part of the `kbd` package. I cannot test it right now, but I think that `setupcon` reloads `/etc/default/keyboard`. If it doesn't, then just reboot ;-)

Comment: installed `kbd`, but still don't have `setupcon` command. I have rebooted, but that did not help.

Comment: `setupcon` is part of `console-setup`, not of `kbd`. As I said, it's `dumpkeys` which is part of `kbd`. But they're both installed by default on Debian, and `dumpkeys` + `loadkeys` are present in any PC Linux distro I know of. If you stripped-down & "optimized" your system, you're in for a ride ;-) I wish you good-luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have been struggling to find information on line about this.  I went with creating a "custom keymap", as suggested by the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration#Creating_a_custom_keymap).  My commands were something like:

```bsh
zcat /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/uk.map.gz > ~/personal.map
vim ~/personal.map
sudo cp ~/personal.map /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/
```

I used `i386/qwerty/uk.map` as a base because it was what I mostly wanted.  It `include`s other maps meaning the file is much smaller than you'd get from `dumpkeys`.  I only wanted to override a couple of modifier keys so this worked well for me.

You can verify it's getting recognized by running:

```bsh
localectl list-keymaps | grep personal
```

and then set it as default by running:

```bsh
sudo localectl set-keymap personal
```